# How to find the row index of an element in a table using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, row

I want to find the row number ( index of the row ) of an element that is present in that row using selenium java.

I have tried this code but it is returning 1 every time.

```
int getElementIndex(WebElement element) {
    WebElement parent = element.findElement(By.xpath(".."));
    ArrayList<WebElement> siblings = (ArrayList<WebElement>) parent.findElements(By.xpath("./" + element.getTagName()));
    int i=0;
    for (WebElement sibling : siblings) {
        if (element.equals(sibling)) {
           System.out.println("Calling from function"+i);
            return i;

        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    throw new NotFoundException(); // Should never happen
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement parent = element.findElements(By.xpath(".."));

    List<WebElement> siblings = parent.findElements(By.xpath("you need to correct your xpath here it looks suspicious"));

for (WebElement sibling : siblings) {
        if (element.equals(sibling)) {
           System.out.println("Calling from function"+i);
            return i;

        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
```